# Adding Secrets and access policy to existing shared keyvault using ARM

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, cicd

I was searching the web after information in regards to the question I have to add secrets and access policies to an existing keyvault in azure shade by others applications using ARM.

I read this [documentation](https://www.codeisahighway.com/there-is-a-new-way-to-reference-managed-identity-in-arm-template/).

What I'm worried about is in regards to if anything existing will be overwritten on deleted as I'm creating a new template and parameter file in my services "solution" so to speak.

And I know that I have my CICD pipelines in devops set to "incremental" in regards to what it should be updating an creating.

Anyone have a crystal clear understanding regarding this?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

So I think I managed to get it right here after all.

I Created a new key vault resource and added a couple of secrets and some access policies to emulate a situation of an already created resource which I want to add new secrets to.

Then I created this template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "keyVault": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Credentials1": {
      "type": "secureString"
    },
    "SecretName1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Credentials2": {
      "type": "secureString"
    },
    "SecretName2": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [

    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVault'), '/', parameters('SecretName1'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "value": "[parameters('Credentials1')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVault'), '/', parameters('SecretName2'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "value": "[parameters('Credentials2')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

What I've learned is that if an existing shared key vault exists which I want to add some secrets to I only have to define the sub resources, in this case the secrets to be added to the existing key vault.

so this worked an resulted in not modifying anything else in the existing key vault except adding the new secrets.

even though this is not a fully automated way of adding a whole new key vault setup related to a new service, as one doesn't connect the new resources correctly by adding their principal ID's (identity). Its good for now as I don't have to add each secret manually. Though I do have to add the principal ID's manually.

Answer (score 0):

When using `incremental` mode to deploy the template, it should not overwrite the things in the keyvault.

But to be foolproof, I recommend you to [back up your keyvault key, secret, certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/backup?tabs=azure-cli) firstly. For the access policies, you can also export the template of the keyvault firstly, save the `accessPolicies` for restore in case.

Comment: I'm still checking the stuff out. So i'va managed to create an arm template just specifying the secrets to add and when deploying the template with its parameters i get an:
 Failed to check the resource group status. Error: {"statusCode":400}.

I have checked the connections, references to RG and resource but nothing helps. Even though my template is valid i suspect there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you redeploy the existing [KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults?tabs=bicep) in incremental mode any child properties, such as access policies, will be configured as they’re defined in the template.  That could result in the loss of some access policies if you haven’t been careful to define them all in your template.  The documentation linked to above will give you a full list of the properties that would be affected.  As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#incremental-mode) this can affect properties even if they’re not explicitly defined.

[KeyVault Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/secrets?tabs=bicep) aren’t a child property of the KeyVault resource so won’t get overwritten. They can be defined in ARM either as a separate resource in the same template or in a different template file.  You can define some, all or none of the existing secrets in ARM. Any that aren’t defined in the ARM template will be left as is.

If you’re using CI/CD to manage your deployments it’s worth considering setting up a test environment to apply the changes to first so you can validate that the result is as expected before applying them to your production environment.

Comment: Hello Nick, I have done that, what i did was creating a new key vault resource and i created an arm template where i only defining the secrets and not the specific resource for the key vault. I deployed the template having already added some access policies and a couple of secrets, emulating an existing setup. And when i deployed my new secrets nothing else got added to the key vault except my new secrets.